# struggling with python code in pearson revel chapter 2

Tags: python

I need some help with some python code. I am working on a college project with pearson revel python and I am having a hard time trying to find the problem with my code. Here is the code I have been using:

```
user_cookies_input = float(input('Enter number of cookies: '))

cups_of_sugar = 1.5
cups_of_butter = 1.0
cups_of_flour = 2.75
number_of_cookies = 48



sugar_output = (user_cookies_input * cups_of_sugar) / number_of_cookies
butter_output = (user_cookies_input * cups_of_butter) / number_of_cookies
flour_output = (user_cookies_input * cups_of_flour) / number_of_cookies

print("You need" + int(sugar_output, '.2f') + "cups of sugar," + int(butter_output, '.2f') +
    "cups of butter, and" + int(flour_output, '.2f') + "cups of flour.")
```

if anyone reads this, please help me out as soon as you can.
Thank you.

Edit: The question given to this project is this below

A cookie recipe calls for the following ingredients:
• 1.5 cups of sugar
• 1 cup of butter
• 2.75 cups of flour
The recipe produces 48 cookies with this amount of ingredients. Write a program that asks the user how many cookies they want to make and then displays the number of cups of each ingredient needed for the specified number of cookies in the following format:

You need 5 cups of sugar, 3 cups of butter, and 7 cups of flour.

Comment: ...what's your problem? What error are you getting? Also, wrap the `int()` in `str()`.

Comment: I think the problem you are facing is that you are passing `'.2f'` to `int`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry for not being precise; I am new to this website. what I am trying to do is get my print statement to print this: "You need 1.5 cups of sugar, 1.0 cups of butter, and 2.75 cups of flour." I have tried many attempts at trying to print this statement, but it would always tell me I am doing something wrong and I don't understand what it is. edit: I've replace the int() with str() but it still is telling I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First of all to concatinate strings with integers/floats you need to convert the integer/float to a string. Second off all, this `'.2f'` from what I know only work's with `f-strings`. Anyways, I think a good habit is to use `f-strings`, they are extremely efficient and simple.

```
print(f"You need {sugar_output:.2f} cups of sugar, {butter_output:.2f} cups of butter, and {flour_output:.2f} cups of flour.")
```

Answer (score 1):

code:

```
user_cookies_input = float(input('Enter number of cookies: '))

cups_of_sugar = 1.5
cups_of_butter = 1.0
cups_of_flour = 2.75
number_of_cookies = 48



sugar_output = (user_cookies_input * cups_of_sugar) / number_of_cookies
butter_output = (user_cookies_input * cups_of_butter) / number_of_cookies
flour_output = (user_cookies_input * cups_of_flour) / number_of_cookies

print("You need " + str(round(sugar_output,2)) + 
    " cups of sugar, " + str(round(butter_output,2)) + 
    " cups of butter, and " + str(round(flour_output,2)) + 
    " cups of flour.")
```

result:

```
Enter number of cookies: 5
You need 0.16 cups of sugar, 0.1 cups of butter, and 0.29 cups of flour.
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be marked as correct for Pearsons mylab

```
cookies=input("Enter number of cookies:")
x=(int(cookies))
s=(x/48)*1.5
b=(x/48)*1
f=(x/48)*2.75
print("You need "+str(s)+" cups of sugar, "+str(b)+" cups of butter," " and " +str(f)+" cups of flour.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

have no spacing after `(cookies:)` in line 1 and change `str(round(flour_output,2))` to `str(round(flour_output,3))`

```
user_cookies_input = float(input('Enter number of cookies:'))
cups_of_sugar = 1.5
cups_of_butter = 1.0
cups_of_flour = 2.75
number_of_cookies = 48

sugar_output = (user_cookies_input * cups_of_sugar) / number_of_cookies
butter_output = (user_cookies_input * cups_of_butter) / number_of_cookies
flour_output = (user_cookies_input * cups_of_flour) / number_of_cookies

print("You need " + str(round(sugar_output,2)) + 
    " cups of sugar, " + str(round(butter_output,2)) + 
    " cups of butter, and " + str(round(flour_output,3)) + 
    " cups of flour.")
```

Output:

```
Enter number of cookies:24

You need 0.75 cups of sugar, 0.5 cups of butter, and 1.375 cups of flour
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_cookies_input = float(input('Enter number of cookies: '))

cups_of_sugar = 1.5
cups_of_butter = 1.0
cups_of_flour = 2.75
number_of_cookies = 48



sugar_output = int((user_cookies_input * cups_of_sugar) / number_of_cookies)
butter_output = int((user_cookies_input * cups_of_butter) / number_of_cookies)
flour_output = int((user_cookies_input * cups_of_flour) / number_of_cookies)
user_cookies_ouput =int(user_cookies_input)


print(f"You need {sugar_output} cups of sugar {butter_output}cups of butter and  {flour_output}  cups of flour to make {user_cookies_ouput} cookies.")
```